# How can I make Dictionary a general IEnumerable for Factory Design Pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, ienumerable, factory

I'm developing a simple WPF Phone Book application which uses XML data.
My idea is to make it more general so that I can use SQL data instead of XML data
if it's required. That's why I chose the basic Factory Design Pattern.

---

Here's my interface (which functions as an abstact class):

```
public interface IPhoneBookData
{
    Dictionary<string,string> GetPhoneBookData();
}
```

---

Here's the Class which inherits from that interface using XML data 
and returns dictionary:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using PhoneBook.BL.XML;
using PhoneBook.BL.XML.ParserXML;

public class PhoneBookDataXml : IPhoneBookData
{
    private string _path;
    Dictionary<string, string> _phoneBookDict = new Dictionary<string,    
                                                               string>();

    public PhoneBookDataXml(string path)
    {
        _path = path;
    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> GetPhoneBookData()
    {
        var phoneBookXml = ParseXml.Deserialize<PhoneBookXml>(_path);

        foreach (var item in phoneBookXml.Properties)
        {
            _phoneBookDict.Add(item.Key, item.Value);

        }

        return _phoneBookDict;
    }


}
```

---

Here's my Factory Class:

```
public static class PhoneBookDataFactory
{
    public static IPhoneBookData GetPhoneBookClass(string input)
    {
        if (input.ToLower().Contains("xml"))
        {
            return new PhoneBookDataXml(input);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

---

And finally here's my MainViewModel Class (WPF MVVM) which uses the factory
for XML:

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    _nameList = new List<string>();
    _phoneList = new List<CustomKeyValuePair<string, string>>();

    //_phoneList = new List<string>();

    var PhoneBookDataInstance =              
                 PhoneBookDataFactory.GetPhoneBookClass("PhoneBook.xml");

    _phoneBookDict = PhoneBookDataInstance.GetPhoneBookData();

    _nameList = _phoneBookDict.Keys.ToList();
}
```

---

I know that Dictionary inherits from ICollection which inherits from IEnumerable but I tried make it general and didn't succeed.

I'll be thankful if you can show me how can the "GetPhoneBookData" that
will return a generic collection and I could  convert it to a Dictionary or any other collection which will be required in the future.

Comment: `Dictionary<string,string>` can be cast down to `ICollection<KeyValuePair<string,string>>`

Comment: Formatting comment: I've edited your question to mark new sections with `---` (which adds a horizontal rule), which is more mobile friendly than `==========================` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` for `_phoneBookDict`

```
ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>> _phoneBookDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

And `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` as a return type for method `GetPhoneBookData()`

```
public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> GetPhoneBookData()
{
    var phoneBookXml = ParseXml.Deserialize<PhoneBookXml>(_path);

    foreach (var item in phoneBookXml.Properties)
    {
        _phoneBookDict.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(item.Key, item.Value));
    }

    return _phoneBookDict;
}
```

Comment: Yuriy, thanks for your quick reply, but there's something I've got to ask:  in the MainViewModel class _phoneBookDict retrieves from GetPhoneBook :        _phoneBookDict = PhoneBookDataInstance.GetPhoneBookData();                     and GetPhoneBook returns now IEnumerable. So how I can convert it to dictionary ? Thanks again, Eli

Answer (score 0):

from you question is not clear what exactly do want, but since Dictionary is already ICollecion, you can use linq extesion method to tranfrom the data to other types. Here's few examples:

Convert to list of CustomKeyValuePairs

```
var phoneList = PhoneBookDataInstance
    .GetPhoneBookData()
    .Select(dictItem => new CustomKeyValuePair(dictItem.Key, dictItem.Value)
    .ToList();
```

---

convert to ObservableCollection of Persons:

```
var persons = PhoneBookDataInstance.GetPhoneBookData()
    .Select(dictItem => new Person 
    {
        Name = dictItem.Key,
        Phone = dictItem.Value
    };

var observableCollection = new ObservableCollection<Person>(persons);
```

---

similarly you can convert to whatever you need